# Execute R scripts through Django hosted on AWS (Elastic Beanstalk)

Tags: python, r, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am currently building a project that uses Django Web Framework (hosted on AWSEB) but also needs to execute some R scripts. I have tried using `subprocess.call(["Rscript", "R_django_test.R"])` but I get the following error "No such file or directory: 'Rscript': 'Rscript'". The code above works locally, but not on the project hosted on AWS. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you insstalled `Rscript`?

Comment: @Marcin How exactly do I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to [use Docker deployment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/single-container-docker.html) if you don't yet. AWSEB uses Amazon Linux 2 a CentOS-based Linux distributive, so follow the guide [How to install R on CentOS](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-r-on-centos-7/) and place the commands into the `Dockerfile`, then `RScript` command will be available in the environment.